# playing audio when a button is clicked in html django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, audio

i have the following html code snippet:

```
<audio controls><source src="{{sound.sound.url}}" type="audio/mpeg" id="yourAudioTag">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var audioElement = document.getElementById('#yourAudioTag');

        $('#play').click(function() {
            audioElement.play();
        });
    });
</script>
```

but it doesn't seem to play the audio when i click on the button PLAY.
how can i do it?

Comment: Is `audioElement` just a new empty element at the time you click it? You may want to select the existing audio element you have, rather than creating one.

Comment: i revised it..it doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

You are never taking the audio file and assigning it to the variable. In your case `audioElement.play();` is playing nothing because it is not linked to anything.

My approach is a little bit different than yours. I decided to put the audio file in the JavaScript directly. You can check it bellow:

Pure JavaScript:

```js
function Play_Audio(){
  var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
  audioElement.src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Metastruct/garrysmod-chatsounds/master/sound/chatsounds/autoadd/snoop_dogg/hold%20up%20wait.ogg";
  document.getElementById("Play_Button").addEventListener("click", function(music){
    audioElement.play();
  }, false);
}
Play_Audio();
```

```html
<button id="Play_Button">Play</button>
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    audioElement.src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Metastruct/garrysmod-chatsounds/master/sound/chatsounds/autoadd/snoop_dogg/hold%20up%20wait.ogg";
    $('#Play_Button').click(function(){
        audioElement.play();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Play_Button">Play</button>
```

Taking the sound from an audio tag:

```js
document.getElementById("Play").addEventListener("click", function(music){
  var audioElement = document.getElementById("Audio");
  audioElement.play();
}, false);
```

```html
<audio id="Audio" controls>
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Metastruct/garrysmod-chatsounds/master/sound/chatsounds/autoadd/snoop_dogg/hold%20up%20wait.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<div id="Play">Play Button</div>
```

PS: It took me more time to find an appropriate audio than to write the snippet.... I think, I have issues!

Comment: i can't give the source of the audio because it is defined this way {{sound.sound.url}}  so how can i do it any other way?

Comment: i tried doing this... var audioElement=document.getElementById('#yourAudioTag');  but no use.

Comment: in this audioElement.src , if i give any src like "D:/student/bark.mp3" it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @Shefali, Sorry for replying so late but I was out of town. I updated my post showing how you can assign an audio tag to a variable. A little mistake that you have done is mixing Javascript and jQuery together. `var audioElement=document.getElementById('#yourAudioTag');` does not require the `#` symbol. The code already know that it is an ID because of the `document.getElementById`. Hopefully, now when we fixed that small error everything will start working. If not we will search for another solutioon.

Comment: @Shefali Happy to help!